# ¿como puedo hacer este diseño?

Tags: php, mysql, css, diseño

Tengo una base de datos con una tabla llamada mesas y quiero obtener el nombre de la mesa y mostrarlo de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo este Código:

```
<?php
  require_once("./2_Vista/html/Navegacion.php");
?>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="\MVC\2_Vista\css\estilo.css">
 <div id="container">
 <table>
        <td colspan="5">Acciones</td>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        if (!empty($dato)):
            foreach ($dato as $key => $value)
                foreach ($value as $v):?>
            <td>
                <a class="button" href="Index.php?m=editar&id=<?php echo $v['NomMesa']?>">
                <?php echo $v['NomMesa']?></a> 
            </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <td colspan="4">No hay registros</td>
            <!–– colspan fuciona celdas consecutivas de una misma fila 1:03:24––>
        <?php endif ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

pero se ve de asi[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como puedo hacer para que cuando introduzca una nueva mesa y cada ves que haya 5 columnas no se me muestre todo en una misma fila si no que se baje una fila mas

Css:

```
#container{
margin: 150px auto;
width: 600px;
}
table{
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr, td{
   border: solid 1px black;
   padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Hola, coloca los CSS que afectan a este diseño para poder ver que modificar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ese caso te recomiendo usar css Grid puesto que con este sistema puedes definir de manera clara tanto las columnas como las filas que deseas que tenga el layout de tu aplicación, por ejemplo:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #a3a3a3;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container .tableGrid {
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  row-gap: 20px;
}
.container .tableGrid .gridItem {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tableGrid">
    <div id="item1" class="gridItem">1</div>
    <div id="item2" class="gridItem">32</div>
    <div id="item3" class="gridItem">4</div>
    <div id="item4" class="gridItem">23</div>
    <div id="item5" class="gridItem">6</div>
    <div id="item6" class="gridItem">31</div>
    <div id="item7" class="gridItem">2</div>
    <div id="item8" class="gridItem">53</div>
    <div id="item9" class="gridItem">56</div>
    <div id="item10" class="gridItem">22</div>
    <div id="item11" class="gridItem">13</div>
    <div id="item12" class="gridItem">34</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Como te puedes dar cuenta, con grid puedes definir la cantidad de columnas que deseas manejar.

En este caso como queremos estrictamente que se mantenga en 5 por fila procedemos a definirlo en el atributo `grid-template-columns`, 5 columnas y la misma medida para cada una.

Para el caso de las filas lo mantenemos en "auto" puesto que la cantidad va a variar, y para que estas no estén juntas le asignamos un `row-gap` de `20px`.

Por último, ¿Por qué no usar flex?: Por la "unidimensionalidad" del sistema, flex solo te permite definir el layout de manera horizontal o de manera vertical, no ambas a la vez, y si deseas hacerlo debes agregar unas cuantas triquiñuelas que francamente no resultan prácticas con la existencia de grid que si te permite definir el layout tanto vertical como horizontalmente.

Saludos :).

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo podrías lograr usando el diseño de *CSS flexbox*

**Posible ejemplo:**

```css
h2 {
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px white;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.item.active {
  background-color: #9900FF;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <h2>::Selecciona la mesa a identificar::</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item active">10</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
    <div class="item">13</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Guia completo de Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)